# How to override delimiters for RegexParsers based parser combinator

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Our parser requires the following two capabilities:

- regex parsing capabilities.
- expand the set of characters that are considered delimiters.

The quandary is that the former requires `RegexParsers` (or its derivatives including `JavaTokenParsers`) whereas the latter requires `StandardTokenParsers`.

The following code would be added to a subclass of `StandardTokenParsers`:

```
// Extend the set of delimiters
class LogLexical extends StdLexical {
  delimiters +=(
    "|", ",", "<", ">", "/", "(", ")",
    ";", "%", "{", "}", ":", "[", "]", "&", "^", "~"
    )

}

// Use the custom lexer to scan the input text
  override val lexical = new LogLexical

  override def parse(input: String): Seq[LogLine] = synchronized {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(input).asInstanceOf[Reader[Char]]
    phrase(allLogTypes)(tokens) match {
      case Success(plan, _) => plan
      case failureOrError => sys.error(failureOrError.toString)
    }
  }
```

However the above approach can not be used for RegexParsers: they do not support the custom Lexer AFAICT.

It is not clear how to obtain both of those capabilities simultaneously.

One difference between those may impact the approach:

- StandardTokenParsers is Char based whereas RegexParsers is String based

But even so - there is *some* set of delimiters being used by RegexParsers: they need to define how the tilde **~** operator is being applied

E.g.   val myParser = someRegexParser ~ someOtherRegexParser

So the tilde is using a set of predefined delimiters to distinguish the beginning of the patterns. But where is that set? And how to change it? Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I would use [fastparse](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse) and ask on the gitter channel.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn  Thx!  fastparse Looks better. I am in a bad way with the standard PC because my regex's  need to support whitespace internally.

Comment: fastparse has MIT license. That will limit a bit since some places require  Apache2

Comment: Fastparse is definitely faster. I think it should become the official followon/replacement of parser combinators. Not sure about the license though.

Comment: I just spent some time with fastparse.  It would have been helpful to point out that it (and probably all PEG parsers?) does not support regex. We need regex.